# VBA - How to access and retrieve the PageSetup.FitToPagesWide variable?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

My Page Breaks can almost be seen on the end of Column H and Row 33.

The end of Column H is 245 pixels  (34.14cm)
The end of Row 33 is 20 pixel (15cm)

I need some guidance on how can I accesss these figures rather than have fixed variables. These figures will change so I need to somehow intelligently retrieve these PageSetup.FitToPagesWide to get the correct figure.

It is somewhat saying, finding the width of the page and finding the height of the page.

If a small snippet of the length of a cell is `Cells(c.row, 2) = Len(c)`

Then what would width of the `PageSetup.FitToPagesWide` be?

Comment: `With Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup 
 .Zoom = False 
 .FitToPagesTall = 1 
 .FitToPagesWide = 1 
End With`

Comment: @MaciejLos     Your response doesn't answer this question as it is slightly different.  I manage to find a way around the fitPage without the VBA, but going back to your PageSetup, I want to access this figure but in centimetres or pixels.

Comment: Please, read this: [PageSetup Object - Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/pagesetup-object-excel). There you may find interesting information.

Comment: @MaciejLos   Thanks, I found PaperSize and xlPaperA4 will resolve my VBA issue. I can use their standard xlPaperA4 measurements and work it from there as the background will do the computation rather than me write extra lines of codes.